# Extrair Conexão JDBC de EntityManager utilizando JTA

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-7, jta

Em um ambiente **JavaEE**, existe a possibilidade de extrair a conexão JDBC(`java.sql.Connection`) utilizando `JTA`?

Tenho um datasource no WildFly, onde eu injeto da seguinte maneira:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Tem alguma forma de extrair a conexão JDBC desse EntityManager?

Encontrei uma forma (mas não funcionou):

```
Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

O seguinte erro foi lançado:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap
>   interface java.sql.Connection

Answer (score 1):

**Hibernate e JPA 2.0**

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;   

 session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

 SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) 
 session.getSessionFactory();

 ConnectionProvider cp = sfi.getConnectionProvider();

 Connection conn = cp.getConnection();
```

**EclipseLink JPA 2.0**

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager; 

 java.sql.Connection connection  entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager

Comment: `SessionFactoryImplementor` não possui o método `getConnectionProvider`

Comment: Qual é a versão da sua implementação  JPA ?

Comment: Java ee 7, ou seja, JPA 2.0

Answer (score 1):

A forma como consegui, foi a seguinte:

```
Session hibernateSession = this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
return ((SessionImpl) hibernateSession).connection();
```